# Sharing iCloud keyvalues between two apps

Tags: ios, icloud

I've followed all the advice I could find to allow two different apps to share small bits of data via iCloud. Everything worked as expected in testing but after both apps have been released on the app store, one of the apps doesn't read the data.

Here's the setup:

```
 app 1 ID: com.mycompany.superapp

 app 2 ID: com.mycompany.superduperapp
```

I've set com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier as com.mycompany.superapp in both app's entitlement file. Both app IDs share the same 10 character prefix.

App 2 functions as expected. But when App 1 (the one whose ID is actually used in the entitlements) tries to access the iCloud data, I see:

```
 Warning: com.mycompany.superapp has no valid com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier entitlement

 Warning: Can't get application info for com.mycompany.superapp
```

Does anyone have any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Verify the actual entitlements file that ends up in the resource directory of the build app has the proper identifier in it.

Comment: @rmaddy - Yes, iCloud is enabled on both app IDs in dev portal.

Comment: @Amro - Good call. I see the file archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent in the app package that worked, but not in the app package that doesn't work. Any idea as to why it would not have been included? If at first you don't succeed submit, submit again ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Double check to make sure iCloud is enabled on that app id as well in the dev portal.